# Scroll as spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/valentincreative/09xnc82h/11/.

CSS :

```
body {
 background-color: #fff;
}

.mask {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #fff;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 overflow: scroll;
}

.sidebar,
.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.shadow {
 box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.header {
 width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
}

.content {
 width: 100%;
}


table {
 table-layout: fixed;
}

td, th {
 width: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 0;
 padding: 8px;
}

tr {
 &:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background-color: #eee;
 }
}
```

JS :

```
content.style.marginTop  = headerHeight + 'px';
content.style.marginLeft = sidebarWidth + 'px';
sidebar.style.paddingTop = headerHeight + 'px';
header.style.paddingLeft = sidebarWidth + 'px';
mask.style.width         = (sidebarWidth + 4) + 'px';
mask.style.height        = headerHeight + 'px';

container.onscroll = function(e) {
 header.style.transform  = 'translateX(-' + container.scrollLeft + 'px)';
 sidebar.style.transform = 'translateY(-' + container.scrollTop + 'px)';

 if (container.scrollLeft > 5 && !sidebar.classList.contains('shadow')) {
  sidebar.classList.add('shadow');
 }

 if (container.scrollLeft < 5) {
  sidebar.classList.remove('shadow');
 }

 if (container.scrollTop > 5 && !header.classList.contains('shadow')) {
  header.classList.add('shadow');
 }

 if (container.scrollTop < 5) {
  header.classList.remove('shadow');
 }
}
```

Currently, only content scroll works as i want. When i scroll in header and sidebar nothing happen.

So, i want to add this two behaviors :

- **when i scroll vertically in the sidebar : content scroll vertically too**
- **when i scroll horizontally in the header : content scroll horizontally too**

I want a result similar to google sheet.

Note : i want to keep only two scroll bars, one at bottom and one at right on the page.

Note 2 : header and sidebar must be always visibles.

Comment: As I look everything works well on firefox. header, row title and cotent scroll well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your css:

```
.sidebar,
.header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
 }
```

With this one:

```
.sidebar,
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Updated Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/valentincreative/09xnc82h/11/

Comment: Thx for answer. But with your solution, header and sidebar are out of screen when scrolling vertically/horizontally. I updated my question.

Comment: Finally, your answer was the big part of solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i fixed it.

With Abhay Naik response for CSS and a little adaption in the original JS.

I change:

```
header.style.transform  = 'translateX(-' + container.scrollLeft + 'px)';
sidebar.style.transform = 'translateY(-' + container.scrollTop + 'px)';
```

to:

```
header.style.transform  = 'translateY(' + container.scrollTop + 'px)';
sidebar.style.transform = 'translateX(' + container.scrollLeft + 'px)';
```

Final working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/09xnc82h/16/